# Java Rest framewok

Tags: java, rest

Which is a good java REST framework?

I would like it to be deployed with Tomcat 6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See my answer on: [RESTFul Web Development with Java EE 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3788230/restful-web-development-with-java-ee-6-what-are-the-options/3794840#3794840):

> I'd recommend you have a look at:
>
> - [RESTLet](http://www.restlet.org/)
> - [Play](http://www.playframework.org/)
> - [Grails](http://www.grails.org/) with the [REST plugin for Grails](http://grails.org/REST+plugin?xhr=true)
> - [Jersey](http://jersey.java.net/)
> - [RestEasy](http://www.jboss.org/resteasy)
>
> (One question though: why specifically
>   do you need to be able to integrate
>   with Java EE?)
>
> EDIT: In the case where you absolutely
>   want to use the Java EE APIs, then as
>   mentioned by BalusC, [JAX-RS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JAX-RS) is
>   your solution of choice. Restlet and
>   Jersey both support it. I don't know
>   about RESTEasy, but the JAX-RS
>   Wikipedia page mentions it does.

Answer (score 5):

Also you can try [Spring Framework 3.x.x](http://blog.springsource.com/2009/03/08/rest-in-spring-3-mvc/).

Answer (score 4):

You can try [RESTEasy](http://www.jboss.org/resteasy). It isn't application server dependent. (Doesn't require an AS at all).

You can also try an alternative, but you really should use a JAX-RS implementation :

- [Jersey](http://jersey.java.net/)
- [Restlet](http://www.restlet.org/)
- [Wink](http://incubator.apache.org/wink/)

Comment: I would be interested to know why one should *really* use a JAX-RS implementation. Is it on technical merit or because it is a JCP standard? What about Spring, Guice, GAE, Android, OSGi and many other non-JCP techs?

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK, [Jersey](http://jersey.dev.java.net/) is the JAX-RS reference implementation. I've used it several times for REST webservice servers.

- Minimal configuration, wide use of Annotations
- Runs in Tomcat, Grizzly, GlassFish and many others...
- The best part, the [Jersey Test Framework](https://jersey.dev.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/user-guide.html#d0e2837) makes it really easy to completely test your service.

Answer (score 2):

I've had a pretty good experience with Jersey. It's pretty easy to integrate it with Tomcat.

Answer (score 2):

I have had good experiences with Restlet: http://www.restlet.org/

Here is a tutorial on running Restlet in Tomcat: http://danilogurovich.wordpress.com/2008/09/23/a-simple-restlet-demo-application/

Answer (score 1):

Here's the best and easiest: http://sparkjava.com/, it works standalone. And here is how http://sparkjava.com/documentation.html#other-webserver to make it work within a server.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.crnk.io/ might also be of interest. Unlike the other libraries here, it can be considered to be a native resource-oriented library and along the way offers various higher-level features like sorting, paging, inclusions, bulk-updates, etc. out-of-the-box.

Answer (score 0):

Play! framework is very good, also more easier than Jersey. You can use with or without tomcat.